# How to avoid getting multiple cookies when login using Cognito

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We are doing authentication using AWS Cognito. The project is contained with an API server and a web server. On the client-side, the user login to the application, through AsureAD, the cognito instance returns a JWT access token. When a user log out from the application, we remove the cookie and signout from cognito.

My problem is that, we need to create only one access token when user login to the application. But it makes two..

```
async logout(req, res, next) {
  try {
    res.header('set-cookie', `SessionCookie-0=; Path=/;`); 
  } catch (error) {
    next(appendExceptionStack(error));
  }
}
```

This is how I reset the cookie when logout. This works when it creates only one access cookie. I think this should be handle in cognito side. Can someone help me to avoid from getting two cookies when login to the application.

Answer (score 0):

What OAuth Flow configuration are you using?  Authorization code grant or Implicit grant?  If you are using Authorization code grant and your backend callback is exchanging the auth code for the tokens, you should get back an access token, refresh token and a id token if you have the openid OAuth scope enabled.  Is it your app that is setting the cookies?  Because when using the Authorization code grant, Cognito only sets two cookies for me.  One is named cognito and the other named XSRF-TOKEN. But in my situation, my app which consumes the Cognito tokens does set our own cookies to store the tokens.  In your case who is creating the cookie named SessionCookie-0?
I think providing more details on your setup will be helpful.